# Función inválida en Firebase

Tags: firebase, polymer

De un tiempo a esta parte Firebase dejó de usar o no reconoce a esta sentencia:

```
firebase.database()
```

Dice que no es una función válida.
¿Cómo o que hay que usar para reemplazar esa función teniendo en cuenta que lo que hago es escribir en la BD

```
        createUser: function(firebaseUser){
        firebase.database().ref("/users/"+firebaseUser.uid).set({
            name: firebaseUser.email,
            email: firebaseUser.email,
            uid: firebaseUser.uid,
            photoURL: "https://scontent-eze1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/294904_455128107836343_243650792_n.jpg?oh=7502f000c9686b4c1022eb2e22d3d243&oe=58B9B4D0"

        })
    }
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

despues de poner toda la configuracion de firebase inicializaste firebase con el siguiente codigo:?
   ***firebase.initializeApp(config);***

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que revisar que hayas incluido todos los componentes de Firebase

Ese error a mi me surgió una vez cuando hice solamente el import de firebase-app y de firebase-auth.
Al no haber incluido firebase-document o firebase-query no estaba disponible el servicio "database"